# Volatile and Lock not working - C# 4.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, locking, volatile

I have a class that reads data from a serial, with a high threshold (1 byte).
I have a variable that stores all the data coming from serial port: _dataReceived.

```
private volatile string _dataReceived;
```

I am using the DataReceived event to store this data, and then I start an action to process it.

```
    private void _port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        string newData = _port.ReadExisting();
        _dataReceived += newData;

        new Action(() =>
        {
            Debug("Data received: {0}", newData);
            ParseAnswers();
        }).BeginInvoke(null, null);
    }
```

Processing it, consists on removing it from variable and treat the answer.
The method ParseAnswers starts as follows:

```
    private void ParseAnswers()
    {
        string cmd = null;
        int idx = -1;

        lock (_dataReceived)
        {
            idx = _dataReceived.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
            if (idx != -1)
            {
                cmd = _dataReceived.Substring(0, idx);
                _dataReceived = _dataReceived.Substring(idx + 2);
            }
            else
                return;
        }
        ...
    }
```

**This works 99.9% of the time.**
But sometimes I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException on this line:

```
                cmd = _dataReceived.Substring(0, idx);
```

Now, my question is:
My variable is volatile what means I am always accessing the real value and not a cache.
I am pretty sure I get this DataReceived event raising all the time (fast), but I am using the lock statement to prevent any other Thread changing this value.
There is no way to get this piece of code (substring) running without having the NewLine inside the string.
And there is no way that this IndexOf is returning a index out of the string.

So... what's damn going on here?

It's very difficult to test anything, because it just happens once a month, but we appreciate any theory about what is actually happening.

Thanks for any suggestions from you!

Comment: design seems flawed.

Comment: Mitch Wheat that's why I posted it. Somewhere we failed, but it's a simple code and I don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: Alex Farber, what modifications you suggest to both get synchronized?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using string concatenation here. Make `_dataReceived` a [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder(v=VS.100).aspx), and call the `Append` method. When you're accessing it, call `_dataReceived.ToString()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is why we recommend to use lock on a private readonly field.

Your `dataReceived` could be changed by another thread in `_port_DataReceived` method(since access is not synchronized) while it is executing `ParseAnswers` for previous event.

So what happens, now two threads race to the `lock(_dataReceived)`, they both are permitted because both use different references of the lock object.

Remember lock statement works on references, `_dataReceived += newData;` changes the reference, so another thread is freely allowed to enter the critical region(as it uses different instance of string now).

Simple fix would be:

```
private string _dataReceived;
private readonly object padLock = new object();

private void _port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string newData = _port.ReadExisting();

    lock (padLock)
    {
        _dataReceived += newData;
    }

    new Action(() =>
    {
        Debug("Data received: {0}", newData);
        ParseAnswers();
    }).BeginInvoke(null, null);
}

private void ParseAnswers()
{
    ...
    lock (padLock)
    {
        idx = _dataReceived.IndexOf(Environment.NewLine);
        if (idx != -1)
        {
            cmd = _dataReceived.Substring(0, idx);
            _dataReceived = _dataReceived.Substring(idx + 2);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Do note that I've removed the `volatile` modifier(which is redundant) and also I've synchronized the access to `_dataReceived` in `_port_DataReceived` method also(very very important)

Comment: Sriram, even if the reference was changed, my lock was holding one reference, a pointer to one address of memory, inside the lock it doesn't have to mantain that reference? Or you mean that just my Substring is working on an updated "_dataReceived".

Comment: That's clearly a race, unpredictable things can happen. You need to synchronize the access everywhere you use the `_dataReceived` field.

Comment: Sriram, correct me if I am wrong, but I understand the the lock SCOPE maintains the address for that scope. Independent of what is happening outside, inside this scope this substring cannot have problems, don't you think? If I changed the value outside, or lock this address or another address outside, this could not happen at all. Do I need to use something like "fixed" that is used for pointers?

Comment: @WagnerBertolini Inside the lock scope, substring can have problems. Your code as written is no better than without any lock at all. let's say thread1 entered lock, and executed upto `if (idx != -1)` statement, then thread2 at the same time enters the lock(possible because lock reference changed), and finds some index `(idx != -1)`, invokes `_dataReceived = _dataReceived.Substring(idx + 2)` and modified the field, now thread1 resumes and tries to execute  `_dataReceived.Substring` finds there is not enough data in string and that explodes. Is that clear? Sorry if I misundertood the question.

Comment: @WagnerBertolini: `lock` doesn't prevent another thread from changing the value. `lock` is a *cooperative* mutual exclusion device, which means that all threads must follow the rules in order for it to work. Your `_port_DataReceived` method breaks the rules by changing the reference without first obtaining the lock.

Comment: Ok, now I got it. I always thought that lock fixes the reference and no one could access that address until I am done. But now I see that is just a flag the scope is not guarantee to be safe of using that address.

Comment: @WagnerBertolini I can't follow your terminology. What do you mean by *But now I see that is just a flag the scope is not guarantee to be safe of using that address*?

Comment: I will try to express my self better. I took a look at MSDN lock documentation and one possibility is to use a constant string as a lock. I did not imagine that before. Then I realized now that using lock just "locks" another line of code trying to do a lock on the same stuff. Get it? I mean, the scope its just to define when to lock/unlock it... First I was thinking that the variable was really locked, including of having changes.

Comment: @WagnerBertolini Yes you got the point. That's a bad idea. Refer my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21473501/2530848). Also in this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473467/c-sharp-lock-string-not-working-for-dynamic-argument/21473501#comment32410421_21473652) I explain why it is bad.

Answer (score 6):

The *volatile* keyword is **never** a solution to synchronization problems.  The bug is clearly visible, you made a hard assumption that the DataReceived event handler is not going to execute again before ParseAnswers() consumed the string and finished running.  That's wishful thinking, your code crashes when the event handler fires again and replaces the string while ParseAnswers() is parsing it.  Using *volatile* actually made it *more* likely for your code to crash :)  You should also have noticed loss of data, that happens when ParseAnswers() runs too late.

The solution is a very simple one, give ParseAnswers() an argument.  Pass the string.

Using Invoke() instead of BeginInvoke() would be a solution too, SerialPort ensures that DataReceived can't be fired when it is still executing.  But it is pretty dangerous, apt to deadlock your program when you try to call Close().